# Inheritance with python unittest

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have two unittest classes in the same file which look like this:

```
class A(unittest.TestCase):
    def some_fun(param):
        # Set class parameters
        self.foo = param + 100
        ...
    def some_fun2():
        do_something with self.foo
        self.assertEqual(self.foo,<check>)
    def some_fun3():
        do_something 

    def setUp(self):
        some_fun(some_foo1)

    def test1(self):
        some_fun2(some_foo1)

    def tearDown(self):
        some_fun3(some_foo1)

class B(unittest.TestCase):
    def some_fun(param):
        # Set class parameters
        self.foo = param + 100
        ...
    def some_fun2():
        do_something with self.foo
        self.assertEqual(self.foo,<check>)
    def some_fun3():
        do_something 

    def setUp(self):
        some_fun(some_foo1)

    def test1(self):
        some_fun2(some_foo1)

    def tearDown(self):
        some_fun3(some_foo1)
```

I want to move some_fun, some_fun2, some_fun3 outside to reduce code repetition keeping in mind that these functions can have assert checks

What is the best way to do this? Im not sure how to do inheritance in this scenario

Edit:
I am facing this weird issue

```
class X(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print(foo) # why is foo=somefun
    def test():
        <something>

class A(X):
    FOO = "SOMESTRING"

    def setUp(self):
        super().__init__(A.FOO)

    def somefun(self):
        self.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this:

```py
class X(unittest.TestCase):

    def some_fun(self, param):
        # Set class parameters
        self.foo = param + 100
        ...
    def some_fun2(self):
        do_something with self.foo
        self.assertEqual(self.foo,<check>)
    def some_fun3():
        do_something

class A(X):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.some_fun(some_foo1)

    def test1(self):
        self.some_fun2(some_foo1)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.some_fun3(some_foo1)

class B(X):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.some_fun(some_foo1)

    def test1(self):
        self.some_fun2(some_foo1)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.some_fun3(some_foo1)
```

Comment: I am this weird issue which I am commenting in the post above

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance rules apply normally here. Create a base class with the methods you want that inherits from `TestCase`:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def some_fun(self):
        ...

    def some_fun2(self):
        ...
```

Create `A` and `B` inheriting from `BaseTest`:

```
class A(BaseTest):
    def test1(self):
        ...

class B(BaseTest):
    def test2(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Hey Enzo, thank you for your response. I am facing a weird issue which I have described above in edit

Comment: I don't understand what's happening with the snippet you provided. Why are you creating a `__init__` inside `X`? `TestCase` uses the first parameter of `__init__` to pass the name of the current method being tested. Also, your `test` method inside `X` does not contain self as first argument, so it's a plain function. Lastly, why are you calling `A`'s `__init__` method inside the setup of `A`? What are you trying to do? You can edit your question with more details and a reproducible example.